# GraphQL Input type deduplication

Tags: graphql

Say I have this:

```
type Page {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  body: String!
  comments: [Comment]
}

type Comment {
   id: ID!
   text: String!   
   someOtherField: String!
   optional: String
}

mutation AddPage (input: AddPageInput): Page!

input AddPageInput {
  title: String!
  body: String
  comment: AddPageCommentInput
}

input AddPageCommentInput {
   text: String!   
   someOtherField: String!
   optional: String
}

mutation AddComment (input: AddCommentInput): Comment!

input AddCommentInput {
   forPageId: ID!
   text: String!   
   someOtherField: String!
   optional: String
}
```

I would like to deduplicate that `AddPageCommentInput` as it has the same fields as `AddCommentInput` except `forPageId`.

What I'm trying to do is to get the `AddPage` resolver to just delegate the `AddPageCommentInput` to `AddComment` resolver (after saving the `Page` and extending the input with `forPageId`)

Is the inheritance (with manually typing the definitions) the only way to make sure things are consistent ?

---

*edit*
I don't have these types, it is just an attempt to provide context for the problem.

A better worded question is : "what options do I have to mimic inheritance for input ?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share common fields btw Input and Type in GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101396/how-to-share-common-fields-btw-input-and-type-in-graphql)

Comment: 'duplicate' of a question asked 3 months after mine... indeed, indeed

Comment: Question age is not the deciding factor when choosing a duplicate. Please see [this discussion on meta.SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315472/old-question-marked-as-duplicate-of-a-new-question).

Answer (score 0):

You can subvert the problem by remodelling the mutation a bit (and making it clearer in the process):

```
input CommentInput {
   text: String!   
   someOtherField: String!
   optional: String
}

input AddPageInput {
  title: String!
  body: String
  comment: CommentInput
}

input AddCommentToPageInput {
   pageId: ID!
   comment: CommentInput!
}

type AddCommentToPagePayload {
    page: Page!
    comment: Comment!
}

mutation AddPage(input: AddPageInput!): Page!
mutation AddCommentToPage(input: AddCommentToPageInput!): AddCommentToPagePayload!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion: you can take out the `forPageId` field out from `AddCommentInput` and use it as a second argument. That will let you discard `AddPageCommentInput` and use `AddCommentInput` in both places.

The code will look something like this:

```
mutation AddPage (input: AddPageInput): Page!

input AddPageInput {
  title: String!
  body: String
  comment: AddCommentInput
}

mutation AddComment (forPageId: ID!, input: AddCommentInput): Comment!

input AddCommentInput {
   text: String!   
   someOtherField: String!
   optional: String
}
```