# Share common fields between Input and Type in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I was wondering if there's a way to share the common fields between Input and Type in GraphQL so that I don't have to define the same set of fields in multiple places.

Example:

```
input PersonInput {
    id: String!
    name: String
    address: String
}

type Person {
    id: String!
    name: String
    address: String
}
```

I know Fragment might be a solution, but if my understanding is correct, using Fragment always requires you to put an ON condition which makes it look like this:

```
Fragment PersonCommonFields on Person {
    ...
}
```

There seems to be no way to specify "on Person/PersonInput".

Comment: I've asked the same question, and it got a [good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452982/reusing-input-type-as-fragment-in-graphql/52453108#52453108) before being closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

GraphQL `fragments` are for querying, not schema definition.

When I started learning GraphQL I was annoyed by this too because I was still thinking RESTfully. In most cases having the freedom to set certain fields non-nullable or remove them entirely from an input/output type is invaluable.

e.g.

```
input CreatePersonInput {
  name: String!
  slug: String
  address: String
}

type Person {
  id: ID! # Autogenerated on the server
  name: String!
  slug: String! # Will always exist, either user provided or computed
  # address: String # Omitted for security reasons
}
```

It may seem like a lot of extra code at first, but the flexibility this brings you over resource based schemas is worth it for long-term projects. I've seen it help out dozens of times.

You should also consider `behavior`/`task-based` mutations over `resource` or "[anemic mutations](https://medium.com/@__xuorig__/graphql-mutation-design-anemic-mutations-dd107ba70496)"

I highly recommend learning about [fat queries](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/thinking-in-graphql.html) and read about Relay Specification. Even if you don't end up wanting Relay on the client, following some of their rules can really clear up common misconceptions about GraphQL.

Comment: still a weird decision on graphql's part imo. Let users separate it _if they choose_, but users should still have the freedom to reuse the same type. For example, what if I defined a `type FullName { firstName: String, lastName: String }`. Why should I have to define a seaprate `FullNameInput`? Not to mention, the primitive types `String` and `Boolean` and `Int` don't have corresponding `StringInput`, BooleanInput`, etc, so they clearly understand that in same cases reuse is fine...