# Is there a way to give a type as input for a mutation, without using the input type in AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, mutation

I have a problem related to a Mutation/Subscription on AWS Appsync, using a local data source (i.e., a Data Source of type NONE).     I need to feed the mutation with data defined as a `type` in the schema and it contains several fields (some other `type` inside it as well). Let's call it  `Profile`

```
type Profile {
  id: ID
  name: String
  address: Address
  email: String
}

type Address {
  street: String
  number: String
  city: String
  zipcode: Int
}
```

`Profile` is already there in the schema as a `type` because it is used in a Subscription.
In order to do so, following the AppSync rules, I should need to create an `input`
and recreate all the fields from the original `type`, let's call it `InputProfile`.

```
input InputProfile {
  id: ID
  name: String
  address: InputAddress
  email: String
}

type InputAddress {
  street: String
  number: String
  city: String
  zipcode: Int
}
```

Now I do not want to merely duplicate all the fields and subfields from the original
data `Profile` but I would like to just use it straight in some way. This comes
from the need to not have duplicates (`Profile` and `InputProfile`) but to just
have all the fields in one `type`. In that way it would easier to maintain and
if any change arises, the modification could be done in the same point in the code
rather than in two points, thus leading to possibile misalignments or mistakes.

In addition to this, please note that in order to achieve this result, it is
also needed to duplicate any complex subfield (i.e. another `type`) in `Profile`
with a corresponding `input` in `InputProfile`. As you could imagine, it leads
to a useless amount of duplicates that should be avoided.

I also tried to feed the mutation directly with `Profile` but AppSync gives an
error as it expects it to be an `input`.

Do you have any advice to overcome this problem and could you propose a more
convenient and elegant solution?

Comment: I'd check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101396/share-common-fields-between-input-and-type-in-graphql) as it's more about a decision made by the GraphQL spec than anything else.

Comment: @NaderDabit agree with you. So from your point of view, it's part of the GraphQL design and it is not intended to be done in other ways (i.e. duplication is unavoidable at certain extent)?

Comment: @TantrixRobotBoy Yes, that is my understanding and interpretation. If you Google around, you will see a few other conversations about this with some interesting takes.